# React - Input Value Clears Out On Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, reactjs

I'm trying to implement some validation for an email based input. It's mostly there, but I'm running into a strange condition.

I'm debouncing the onChange function that includes some validation and validating again on submit. If the user submits an invalid string before the debounce catches it, the submit function will catch it and set the component state to invalid, but only until the debounce hits, at which point the debounce sets the state back to valid, because it seems like the form submit is clearing out the underlying value of the input field. I have a preventDefault in my submit function, but it still seems like the event.target is getting emptied whenever that submit function is fired. I would like to keep the event.target/input value in sync. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import _ from 'underscore';
import classNames from 'classnames';

class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isValid: true
        };
        this.validateOnChange = _.debounce(this.validateOnChange,500).bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.validateEmail = this.validateEmail.bind(this);
    }


    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(this.validateEmail(event.target[0].value)){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/search?email=' + event.target[0].value
            })
            .done((data) => {
                this.props.getNewImage(data, false);
            })
            .fail(() => {
                this.props.getNewImage('/img/obi.gif', true);
            });
        }else {
            this.setState({isValid: false});
        }
   }

   validateOnChange(event){
       this.setState({isValid: (event.target.value ? this.validateEmail(event.target.value) : true)});
    }

    validateEmail(input){
        var re;
        re = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)\b/i;

        return re.test(input);
    }

    render() {
        var classes = classNames({
            'form-control': true,
            'valid': this.state.isValid,
            'invalid': this.state.isValid === false
        });
        return(
            <form ref='searchForm' className='navbar-form navbar-left animated' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <div className='input-group'>
                    <input type='text' className={classes} placeholder="Enter Email!" onChange={this.validateOnChange.bind(this)} />
                  <span className='input-group-btn'>
                      <button className='btn btn-default' type="submit"><span className='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>Search</button>
                  </span>
                </div>
                {this.state.isValid ? null : <span className="invalid-text">Invalid Email Address</span> }
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: Does this work for you? http://jsbin.com/motehejuwa/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

you can use `linkState` of `react/linkState` to handle the onChange event of an input element.

```
<input
   min="1"
   max="10"
   type="number"
   className="form-control"
   valueLink={linkState(this, 'qty')} />
```